# sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPlatformFont exception

Tags: java, exception, fonts, openshift

Im using Openshift Platfrom (jre 1.6) to deploy my java application with jasper reports. From last few days Im receiving following exception during jasper report execution.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPlatformFont(FontManager.java:3409)
    sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment$2.run(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:263)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.<init>(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:164)
```

any info how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: Same issue with 1.6.0_39, but 1.6.0_36 works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Our sysadmins had updated java to
java version "1.6.0_39"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.11) (rhel-1.13.11.1.el6_8-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

on
Linux version 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-031.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Sep 10 13:42:16 EDT 2015

I got around that problem by installing these with yum

dejagnu.noarch                                         1:1.4.4-17.el6
dejavu-sans-mono-fonts.noarch                          2.33-1.el6
dejavu-serif-fonts.noarch                              2.33-1.el6

```
yum install dejagnu.noarch 1:1.4.4-17.el6
yum install dejavu-sans-mono-fonts.noarch 2.33-1.el6
yum install dejavu-serif-fonts.noarch 2.33-1.el6
```